# keep variable constant from function to function

Tags: php, mysql, variables

i have a function

```
function createRandomString($length) {
    $string = md5(time());
    $highest_startpoint = 32-$length;
    # use hexdec to get a "number only" format
    $randomString = hexdec(substr($string,rand(0,$highest_startpoint),$length));
    return $randomString;
}
$randomID = createRandomString(7);
```

and i want to be able to use the random string created in other functions

for example:

```
function new() {
echo '<input name="id" type="text" value="'.$randomID.'" disabled="disabled">';
}
```

However the random ID does not show up in the new function (aka its blank).

I need to define the random ID as a variable once so that the number remains constant throughout the script since if I defined it in every function you would get a different number using this method.

Is there a way of defining the variable randomID using the script at the top and keeping it constant throughout all functions calling it?

Comment: Couldn't you set a global variable from the function?

Comment: how would one do that within the rhelm of the this scenario?

Comment: Put the variable in the class outside of all functions. Preferably right after the class statement. (Where you would define a TAG variable.)

Comment: already tried that. doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I don't think "new" is a legal name for a function...

Comment: its just some random thing i created for this example ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, though I'd advise against it, the easiest fix for what you're trying to do in the `new` function is:

```
function new()
{
    global $randomID;
    echo '<input....'.$randomID.'/>';
}
```

But there are a few more, and better ways to achieve the same result:

using classes:

```
class randomOutput
{
    protected static $_randomID;
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$_randomID;//can be initialized here, using the same code you have in your createRandomId function
    }

   public function output()
   {
       echo '<input...'.self::$_randomID.'/>';
   }
}
```

using arguments, as Zulkhaery Basrul's answer shows. You can make the argument optional by giving a default value of `null` in your function defenition.
 However, since that answer is now deleted:

```
function new($id)
{
    echo '<input...'.$id.'/>';
}

//with default val:
function new($id = null)
{
    $id = ($id === null ? createRandomId(7) : $id);
    echo '<input...'.$id.'/>';
}

$randId = createRandomId(7);
new($randId);
//some time later
new($randId);
```

Declaring constants:

```
function createRandomString($length)
{
    if (defined(RANDOM_STRING_CONST))
    {
        return RANDOM_STRING_CONST;
    }
    //make your randomID, then:
    define('RANDOM_STRING_CONST',$randomID);
    return RANDOM_STRING_CONST;
}
```

Classes have constants, too. You can define them in an abstract class, so all child classes have access to the same randomId. As an added bonus (*and* potential pitfall) class constants, defined at the parent level can be overruled by the child class. So be careful!

Comment: You're also missing the most obvious way - just pass `$randomID` as an argument

Comment: There was an answer here already pointing that out. Just below the rudimentary class, I mention the possibility of function arguments and assigning them a default value, too :P

Comment: hmm. For some reason that answer wasn't visible when I posted my comment

Comment: It would appear to be deleted, indeed. I edited my answer to provide an example buth with default value and without

Comment: Does any of this code actually run? I'm pretty sure using "new" as a function name causes fatal errors....

Comment: It won't run, I guarantee. Though sometimes renaming the op's functions causes confusion, so I stuck with the names - even though they are reserved words

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem True. Don't confuse the OP. I suppose one way you could prevent confusion is rename to "_new" and then put a note in bold at the top of the answer to explain what/why...

Comment: Haha yea it was just an example I didnt think of the implications of naming it new.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a global variable. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

However, using global variables is considered poor programming practice. It is better to organize your code properly into classes, and then use class and instance variables.

I recommend that you read a good book about PHP or about object-oriented programming principles.

Comment: +1: I agree, in this day an age (of OOP), using globals is evil, and shows a bad class design (or lack of classes all together). The best approach is to have a solid, well designed class library. Constants are a necessity, in some cases but not for what the OP is describing here.

Comment: OOP is great. I've been doing it since it was invented. However, since an app is one big class, what's not oop about a global variable pertinent to the whole class? Not using globals for some  variables makes things like onPause and onResume really cumbersome. Just wondering...

Comment: Globals do have a place even in modern programming. It's good to _minimize_ use of the global namespace, but you cannot totally eliminate everything from it. A good programmer knows all his tools and when to use them. This is why I suggested that the OP do some reading :-)

Comment: Of course globals have their use, but not in this case. Calling it evil (a bit harsh, I admit), I wanted to point out that, as soon as you type the word `global`, you _have_ to ask yourself at least 10 times, "Is this really the best way".

Comment: Playing "devil's advocate" I say there is some small chance that the OP's entire project is under 50 lines and is completely contained in one PHP file. If that were true, using globals would only be a small sin. :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function createRandomString($length) {
    $string = md5(time());
    $highest_startpoint = 32-$length;
    # use hexdec to get a "number only" format
    $randomString = hexdec(substr($string,rand(0,$highest_startpoint),$length));
    return $randomString;
}
$randomID = createRandomString(7);


function newfunction($arg) {
echo '<input name="id" type="text" value="'.$arg.'" disabled="disabled">';
}

newfunction($randomID);
?>
```